# Javascript FORs - differences and similarities in a particular case

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I have one doubt that arose while I was trying to redirect to another page with submit.

Why if I replace the code `for(var i=0;i...;i++)` with the line `for(i in arreglo)`, in the redirection (onsubmit) only it shows `alert('one')` instead of both, `alert('one')` and `alert('two')`?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registro Javascript</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function inicio(){
                document.getElementById("formulario").onsubmit=verificar;
            }

            function verificar(){
                var arreglo=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                var camposVacios="";
                var numVacios=0;
                alert('one');
                for(var i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
                    if(arreglo[i].getAttribute("type")=="text"){
                        if(arreglo[i].value.length==0){
                            camposVacios+="\n- "+arreglo[i].id;
                            numVacios=numVacios+1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert('two');
                if(numVacios>0){
                    alert('Los siguientes campos estan sin completar : '+camposVacios);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            function verificarObjeto(objeto){
                if(objeto.value.length==0)
                    alert('El campo '+objeto.id+' debe tener al menos un caracter.');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="inicio()"> <br>
        <form id="formulario" method="post" action="other.html"> <br>
            Nombre : <input type="text" id="nombre" onblur="verificarObjeto(this)"/> <br>
            Apellido Paterno: <input type="text" id="apellido paterno" onblur="verificarObjeto(this)"/> <br>
            Apellido Materno: <input type="text" id="apellido materno" onblur="verificarObjeto(this)"/> <br>

            Edad : <input type="text" id="edad" onblur="verificarObjeto(this)"/> <br>
            Direccion : <input type="text" id="direccion" onblur="verificarObjeto(this)"/> <br>
            Telefono : <input type="text" id="telefono" onblur="verificarObjeto(this)"/> <br>
            Email : <input type="text" id="email" onblur="verificarObjeto(this)"/> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrarse"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Limpiar campos"/>
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: If alert one is not being shown is because an error has occurred. Check console logs (and you should use console.log("one") instead alert("one") )

Comment: Did you only replace the `for(...)` line? Or did you also alter the following tree lines accordingly? Because `i` no longer holds a numerical value, and accessing the array with an Element rather than a numerical value ought to cause an error.

Comment: I'm confused, why  the classical FOR works, and the "compressed" FOR doesn't ? 
i 've checked the code and i don't understand why any alerts after the cycle are not showed when i use the "compressed" FOR.

*i 'm not native of english XD

Comment: The form `for (var x in y)` iterates over an object's properties, which happens to be array indices for arrays. But maybe `arreglo` is not really an array, but another object pretending to be one. Did you try logging the value of `i` inside the loop?

Comment: yes, with the form `for (var i in arreglo)` alerts work and it's possible obtain arreglo[i] and i (inside the cycle), after the cycle is not possible see the alerts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you get with `.getElementsByTagName` is not an `array` but is a `nodeList`. You have to turn it to an array before you put it in a loop to use more efficiently and in those cases i prefer `.forEach` rather than for.

To make the array :

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arreglo);
```

To loop the array

```
array.forEach(function(elem){
  if(elem.getAttribute("type")=="text"){
  ....
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qx8P3/1/)**